# SQL query for nested one-to-many relations, as aggregated arrays?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on a kanban board using Postgres as my database. Normally I would use MongoDB for something like this, but I'm trying to practice and improve my understanding of relational databases.

So I have boards, which can have many lanes, and lanes can have many cards. Boards, lanes, and cards are 3 tables in the database. Lanes have a boardId which is a board.id value, cards have a laneId which is a lane.id value.

I want to query for a board by its id, but also have it include an array of its lanes. Then, I want each of the lanes to include an array of its cards. Like this:

```
{
id:123
title: 'Board title',
lanes: [{id: 0, title: 'Lane title', cards: [{id: 0, text: 'Card text'}]}, {id: 1, title: 'Lane title', cards: [{id: 1, text: 'Card text'}, {id: 2, text: 'Card text'}]}]
}
```

I have the first part down with a query that gets a board, then creates an array of lanes. Not sure if this is the 'right' way to do it, but here it is, with an example looking for a board with id '123':

```
select "boards"."id" as "boardId", "boards"."title" as "boardTitle", ARRAY_AGG(json_build_object('id', lanes.id, 'title', lanes.title)) as lanes from "boards" inner join "lanes" on "boards"."id" = "lanes"."boardId" and "boards"."id" = 123 group by "boards"."id"
```

But I'm not sure how I would get the cards to be included as a cards array for each element in the lanes array. My guess is that I could add another join like `"cards" on "lanes"."id" = "cards"."laneId"`... but then I don't know how I would include the cards for each lane in the json_build_object.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to accept json from the database in order to put rows inside of arrays.

I would build this up using CTEs to make it clear as possible:

```
with agg_lanes as (
  select lane_id as id, jsonb_agg(cards) as "cards"
    from cards 
   group by lane_id
), agg_boards as (
  select b.id, b.title, jsonb_agg(a) as "lanes"
    from agg_lanes a
    join lanes l on l.id = a.id
    join boards b on b.id = l.board_id
   group by b.id, b.title
)
select to_json(a)
  from agg_boards a
;
```

[Working fiddle here.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mAmUEcxhM89mLAG4Zm1NKt/1)